# Use of C2D_MESSAGE permission in Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to understand how C2D_MESSAGE permission is being used by the GCM apps. My guess is that GCM service client app will send a broadcast to the subscriber app via the sendBroadcast(Intent intent, String receiverPermission) API method, where the receiver permission will be set as the C2D_MESSAGE permission defined by the subscriber app. However, I wasn't able to find this in the Google Play Store app (which I believe is the GCM service client app?) itself. Am I looking at the wrong place? Or is it the case that this is done in a different way? All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The message is technically sent to the subscriber (who is the GCM client) from the GCM server (app to app GCM is still routed through a server).

When the subscribing device (or client) receives the message, the message looks for that specific permission. The permission is constructed by appending C2D_MESSAGE to the end of your package name. The full permission (with package name) lets the message know that this app is expecting it. It is to prevent other apps from receiving this message.

If you are new to GCM, I recommend using Firebase as the old GCM is deprecated in favor of Firebase.

Comment: So which app sends the broadcast message to the subscriber app? Can you point me to where in the GCM service app code (whoever that is) this is done?

Comment: The GCM server hosted by Google sends the message to your device. To receive messages you would have first registered your device with a server correct? That server posts a message to the GCM server which sends it to the device in turn.

Comment: The GCM server code is owned by Google (their proprietary material). It does not send a broadcast, instead it knows the specific device and the package name of the app it should send to (it knows the package name at the time you register the app). The device in turn sends this as a broadcast internally

Comment: I was asking for the service app code (the code that runs on the device), not the server code itself. So I'm interested in where exactly this "The device in turn sends this as a broadcast internally" is done.